# What is the germ layer origin of human lung fibroblasts?

Tags: development

What is the germ layer origin of human lung-derived fibroblasts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All normal fibroblasts are mesenchymal in origin, including lung fibroblasts. In certain situations, usually injury related, epithelial cells can undergo an epithelial to mesenchymal transition (EMT).

Comment: Even dermal fibroblasts?

Comment: Yes, all fibroblasts with the exception I listed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The table at http://genome-mirror.duhs.duke.edu/ENCODE/cellTypes.html lists many commercially available cell lines. The four lung fibroblast lines, including adult and fetal, are listed as endodermal in origin.